# Delete everything between <> in text in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, tags

I'd like to make a "clear" button for my textarea which will delete every <> and anything between them.
So lets say I have:

```
<div id="markred">Hello World! My name is <b>John!</b></div>
```

And after the "cleaning" function I'd like it to be:

```
Hello World! My name is John!
```

I can't really figure out how to do this, tried a few Regex and then realized I don't really know how to write decent regex...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) like,

```
alert($('#markred').text());// will give only text not html tags
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j73Ud/)

**Alternatively,**

```
$('#markred').text(function(){
    return $(this).text();// will remove <b> tag
});
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$('#markred').text('');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('#markred > b').contents().unwrap();
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P4Pt5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$('#markred').text();`

That would return the text (and only the text) inside the selected div.

See http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to make a "clear" button for my **textarea**

So, assuming that

```
<div id="markred">Hello World! My name is <b>John!</b></div>
```

is literally the text content of the textarea, you can first parse the content and then use DOM manipulation to filter out and keep all text nodes. For example:

```
$('#textarea').val(function (index, value) {
    return $($.parseHTML(value))
        .find('*') // find all element nodes
        .addBack() // include root node(s)
        .contents() // include all text nodes
        .map(function () { // filter and get text node value
            return this.nodeType === 3 ? this.nodeValue : null;
        }).get().join(''); // concatenate text values
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac3Uw/)